# Поиск std::nullopt и nullptr с помощью std::ranges::find не компилируется

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, optional

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>
#include <optional>
#include <ranges>

std::optional<int> x[42];

auto it  = std::find(x, x + 42, std::nullopt);
auto it2 = std::ranges::find(x, x + 42, std::nullopt);

std::unique_ptr<int> y[42];

auto it3 = std::find(y, y + 42, nullptr);
auto it4 = std::ranges::find(y, y + 42, nullptr);
```

Почему `std::find` компилируется, а `std::ranges::find` - нет? [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:23,endLineNumber:14,positionColumn:23,positionLineNumber:14,selectionStartColumn:23,selectionStartLineNumber:14,startColumn:23,startLineNumber:14),source:%27%23include+%3Calgorithm%3E%0A%23include+%3Cmemory%3E%0A%23include+%3Coptional%3E%0A%23include+%3Cranges%3E%0A%0Astd::optional%3Cint%3E+x%5B42%5D%3B%0A%0Aauto+it++%3D+std::find(x,+x+%2B+42,+std::nullopt)%3B%0A//+auto+it2+%3D+std::ranges::find(x,+x+%2B+42,+std::nullopt)%3B%0A%0Astd::unique_ptr%3Cint%3E+y%5B42%5D%3B%0A%0Aauto+it3+%3D+std::find(y,+y+%2B+42,+nullptr)%3B%0A//+auto+it4+%3D+std::ranges::find(y,+y+%2B+42,+nullptr)%3B%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:37.90381403298274,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),k:28.762852633683934,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

> error: no match for call to '(const std::ranges::__find_fn)
> (std::optional [42], std::optional*, const std::nullopt_t&)'
>
> error: no match for call to '(const std::ranges::__find_fn)
> (std::unique_ptr [42], std::unique_ptr*, std::nullptr_t)'

Comment: а вот так работает `auto it2 = std::ranges::find(x, std::optional<int>{});`